# PHP date() function inserting zeros into database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an array like so which has the column names of the table on the left and the associating values on the right.

```
            $proceduredata = array 
            (
                'patient_id' => $patientfk,
                'name_id' => $procedurenamefk,
                'department_id' => $departmentfk,
                'dosage_id' => $dosagefk,
                'edocument' => NULL, //not implemented yet
                'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('userID'),
                'duration' => NULL, //not implemented yet
                'submitted' => date('d-m-Y H:i:s', now()),
                'comment' => NULL, //to be implemented

            );
```

This array is then passed into a SQL insert function. The insert works fine but my "Submitted" column is getting values of this only:

> 0000-00-00 00:00:00

I made sure the time formats are matching? Is there something I have missed thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the date format

```
  submitted' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', now())
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the "now()" function is a sql function and you are using PHP with the "date()" funciton. Try changing "now()" to "time()" which will give you a proper unix timestamp that the "date()" function can use to create a properly formatted date.

EDIT: I just realized I am not familiar with codeignighter, so please excuse me if the "now()" function is part of that framework.

Answer (score 0):

now() is not a function, change now() to time(). Alternatively, date()'s second paramater is optional if you omit it date automatically uses the current date/time:

```
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

will echo the current date/time in the format requested.